# Handling multiple request with different parameter in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

How to handle multiple request with different parameters in redux?

When making api req like `/api/details?filterby=name` and `/api/details?filterby=day` both get store in a state `detaildata`, how to get both data.

I have action and store which generates back end data for each request, I need to render both data and display, in my scenario am getting latest data

```
import React from "react";
class SalesAnalytics extends React.PureComponent {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
     filterby =""
   }
 }

  callFetch = (filterby) =>{  
    this.props.dispatch(
      querySalesSummaryInfo(filterby)
    )
  }

  render(){
   const summ = this.callFetch("name");
   const add = this.callFetch("day");
   const {saleSum} = this.props.detailData // backenddata 
   return(
    <div>
      byName: {saleSum}
      byDay:{saleSum}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: modify your state to support your scenario. use an array for details